# How to compare two different types of array list in android?

Tags: java

I want to compare two different types of array list i.e.

`ArrayList<A> list1 = new ArrayList<A>();`
`ArrayList<B> list2 = new ArrayList<B>();`

So I want to compare `list1` and `list2` and get the count of indexes at which both are same?

Comment: How can two items be the same if they are of different types?

Comment: how can you compare say ObjectInputStream and inteter???

Comment: first you should define what does it mean element of type A to be "the same" as element of type B.

Comment: The A and B both are different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *So I want to compare list1 and list2 and get the count of indexes at which both are same?*

(I have no idea what types you have for `A` and `B`, but I'll just assume that it makes sense to compare them using `equals`.)

You can use `Iterator`s to iterate over the lists, and use an if-statement to increment a counter for each element that equal.

```
Iterator<A> iter1 = list1.iterator();
Iterator<B> iter2 = list2.iterator();

int sameCounter = 0;

while (iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext())
    if (iter1.next().equals(iter2.next()))
        sameCounter++;
```

Answer (score -5):

Use size method for arraylists to get maximum indexes:

If (list1.size() == list2.size()){
......
}

If elements are of different types you can not compare them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But why we can't compare different types of element?

Comment: What's the error message? What types are you trying to compare?

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't understand your question, so my previous answer is not correct (My English understanding, :( )